# Using Perl to open a file and preview its contents

Tags: perl

I am working on a project for school, and this class is very non-descriptive. I don't understand what is going on and why I cannot get a file to display.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\n+--------------------------+";
print "\n| The File Search &        |";
print "\n|         Display Tool     |";
print "\n+--------------------------+";

print "\nPlease enter the file you would like to read (with full path): \n";

my $FILE = <STDIN>;
chomp $FILE;
sleep 1;

open (FILE, "$FILE");
print "  Here is the secret information you seek supreme leader: \n";
print "==============================================================";

while ($FILE) {
    chomp $FILE;
    open $FILE;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried all kinds of different combinations but it only ever leads to errors.

---

#### Update

So I made some revisions to the code per everyone's suggestions (see below). After running the script it returns the following error

```
readline() on unopened filehandle at test.pl line 30.
```

In my code below, I think I opened the filehandle but this error is making me think I messed something up with it somewhere near the open command.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\n+--------------------------+";
print "\n| The File Search &        |"; #Not so fancy banner! 
print "\n|         Display Tool     |"; 
print "\n+--------------------------+";

print "\n   Welcome to the Tool. It is still being tested!!\n";
print "\n    Please enter the file you would like to read: ";

my $filename = <STDIN>; #define the variable for the filename

if ( not -f $filename ) #This checks the validity of the file
{
print "Filename does not exist\n";
exit;
}

sleep 1;

print "  Here is the secret information you seek supreme leader: \n";
print "==============================================================\n";

open my $filehandle, "<", $filename; #or die $!

while ( <$filename> ) { #While loop to read each line of the file
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

I commented out the or die portion of the open string because it was just killing the script and I wanted to see what was wrong. I am a little confused about the "<", that is in the open statement. @Borodin

Comment: Can I just say - usually home work questions mean bad questions. This is actually a good question, and one that's clear and answerable.

Comment: @Borodin Any suggestions to the error?

Comment: You should really open a new question rather than update an existing one -- Stack Overflow is very different from a forum. There are two issues here. If the `or die` was killing the script then it means the open was failing for some reason and there is no point in trying to read from the handle. Secondly, you have `<$filename>`, which is a throwback to your original code: you can't read from a file name! I also suggest using `$fh` instead of `$filehandle` as the latter isn't visually very different from `$filename`

Comment: Something that may not be clear -- `<$fh>` is a `readline` on filehandle `$fh`

Comment: The `open` call has one-, two-, and three-argument forms. The first is very old and best forgotten. The second is presumably what you're familiar with, where the open mode is mashed in with the file name and you write `open my $fh, '<myfile.txt'`, and you can omit the `<` for read mode. This is still a bit of a hack, and the last form is now considered best practice, where each piece of input is kept separate. It means you can open files with names like `<` which are valid on Linux platforms but can't be opened any other way

Comment: Yours should read from a file *handle*. Currently, you're reading from a file *name*.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question when you have a new question. It is ok to do this, and doesn't invalidate previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

You are just getting your variables mixed up. You are using `$FILE` and `FILE`, and (invisibly) `$_`. `$FILE` starts off as the *name* of the file, but you also read from it, `chomp` it and `open` it which is wrong

You should `open` file names, *read from* file handles, and `print` what you have read (or any other value). And it is best to use lower case for all local variables and reserve capitals for globals

Your code should look like this. I have used the *lexical* file handle `$fh` instead of the old-fashioned global one. Putting variables in quotes like `"$FILE"` is wrong: at best it makes no difference, but it may break your program. Also, `<$fh>` in a `while` loop like that reads into the default variable `$_`, which is also the default parameter for `chomp`. Think of it as the pronoun ***it*** in English

```
open my $fh, '<', $file_name;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Effective use of the implicit variable is an important `perl` skill. One you grok it, there's some lovely code you can write, but until you do there's many pitfalls that await!

Comment: Your comments have definitely spread some light into what I was doing wrong. The professor just handed out the assignment and I was on my own. The explanation of using global vs lexical filehandles in this situation makes more sense; as I just did some research into why they are better than global variables for certain things. It definitely helps to have someone who knows what they are doing who is willing to help and explain things like you have. I assumed that once you had defined the global variable you had to follow it through. I can definitely see now where my mistakes were based on that.

Comment: @undecisive: It's encouraging to find a student that is willing to learn! What do you mean by *I was on my own*? The big advantage of lexical file and directory handles over global ones is firstly the same as the advantage of *any* local identifier over a global one -- you are preserved from accessing and modifying the wrong variable. In Perl's case you also have the advantage that the handle will be closed when it goes out of scope, saving you from writing housekeeping code

Comment: @Borodin Basically the teacher gave us a very brief overview on perl and how to write hello world, then taught us how to use chop and chomp to remove characters. The next item was now go write a script to open a file and read the contents inside. So I have been testing and trying different things in the scripts to see if I could get it to open even trying things like File::Find to locate the file. That was far to advanced at this point and I am definitely going to try and get a better grasp on the lexical filehandles and using the "basic" commands before trying to add in modules.

Comment: @Borodin so in essence, it was a giant leap forward into perl with very minimal instruction. So I have been trying this all week and google searching; with no avail because I didn't really understand what I was looking for, and finally decided that I needed help from some more experienced people, and I have used stackoverflow for python questions pretty recently.

Comment: @undecisive: You can forget about `chop` -- it is of very little use, and was the predecessor to `chomp` until they decided that removing the last character only if it happened to be a line terminator was much more useful. You can look at some of the modules. Some, for instance `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils`, just add new operators to the language.

Answer (score 2):

The core problem here is that you're re-opening, not actually reading.

To open a file:

```
open ( my $filehandle, "<", $filename ) or die $!;
```

The `die` is quite important, because it'll tell you if there's a problem opening the file. `$!` is the 'status code' of the open operation, so it'll tell you if the file couldn't be found.

But *all* this does is 'set' `$filehandle` to give you an access point.

To get the contents of the file, you need to *read* it, and in `perl` this is done with `<>`.

So:

```
my $line = <$filehandle>
```

Will read a single line.

If you want to read more than a single line, then you do it in a while loop.

```
while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ) {
    print $line;
}
```

You might also find it useful to test whether a file exists before doing this:

```
if ( not -f $filename ) { 
   print "$filename does not exist\n";
   exit; 
}
```

Comment: Sobrique, this is similar to what @Borodin was saying. I like the idea to test if the file exists first, so that it gives the program an exit point in the event the file does not exist. I was wondering what the '<>' did in Borodin's script and was about to go reference it but you already spelled it out. You guys have been very helpful for a super new perl user here; even more so than my professor, and I am going to try and use the items you all have mentioned such as lexical filehandles, and the read parameters to try and gain a better understanding of these basic perl functions.

Comment: We all started at the beginning. Keep asking good questions, and you will learn a lot from this site.

Comment: Agreed. We all start out as newbies but eventually gain the knowledge to be successful in a task. I just hope that I can become knowledgeable in perl as well as python and pass on some knowledge to a person who is new to either in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues: one, you read from `FILE` the same way you read from `STDIN`, with the `<>` operator. Two, assuming you want to display the contents of `$FILE`, your while loop should look like

```
while (<FILE>) {
    print;
}
```

This uses the implicit variable `$_` to store the line read from `FILE` each time through the loop, which is the same variable `print` uses with no other argument. More explicitly, you might write

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    print "$line";
}
```

`chomp` isn't needed, since `print` won't print an additional newline unless you tell it to. You could also write

```
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

or

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    print "$line\n"
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest renaming one of the filename (`$FILE`) or the file handle (`FILE`), as that's just a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Agreed; I usually use `FH` for the file handle and `$fname` for the file name.

Comment: @chepner: You should also use lexical file handles -- `$fh` instead of `FH`

Comment: Chepner thanks for the advice. I think what I was trying to do was your last example with the chomp and then print it. Clearly I did that extremely wrong but hey I'm learning and you all are nice enough to break it down step by step for me. 

Jim,  your advice has been noted, I will steer clear of using Capitals for variable names and leave capitals for the file handles. (I think that is what you are saying)

Comment: I do use lexical file handles, but it seemed like I was piling enough new concepts into the answer as it was.